# How to insert a image gallery into node body?

Tags: entities, media

I created a gallery using fields (gallery formatter and lightbox) but i can only add the gallery before or after the field body.

I tried the insert module but it can only add one picture and not the whole gallery.

Is there a way to insert the gallery into the field body at a specific location?

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not work for you, try [WYSIWYG FIELDS](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_fields) module. If it doesnt work, I cannot think of another turn-key solution.

> The Wysiwyg Fields module is bridge between CCK Fields and the Wysiwyg
>   module, allowing most (if not all) CCK fields to be turned into a
>   Wysiwyg button for a convenient inline solution.

Comment: It adds the gallery field into the body, but also adds some unnecessary html so that my gallery doesn't work anymore.